# saving nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have a form that has a nested form like this:

```
<%- for subscription in @task.subscriptions -%>
    <%- semantic_fields_for "task[subscription_attributes][]", subscription  do |subscription_form|%>
        <%- subscription_form.inputs do -%>
            <%= subscription_form.input :workhours, :label => subscription.user.full_name%>
        <%- end -%>
    <%- end -%>
<%- end -%>
```

And on the task model I have:

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscriptions
  attr_accessible :mission_id, :statuscode_id, :name, :objectives, :start_at , :end_at, :hours, :testimony ,:subscriptions_attributes
```

In the form (view) I get the correct values on the workhours fields. But when I change the values and hit the submit button, the values are never changed.
I can't figure out why...

I see in the console that this is building up on the tasks attributes. So the values are passing to the controller.

```
"subscription_attributes"=>{"11"=>{"workhours"=>"20"}, "12"=>{"workhours"=>"303"}, "9"=>{"workhours"=>"120"}, "10"=>{"workhours"=>"10"}}
```

On the tasks_controller I have:

```
@task.update_attributes(params[:task])
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting in your first code paste.

Comment: Does your call to `update_attributes` return true?

Comment: Yes, the @task attributes get saved. Only the subscriptions attributes are ignored. I have done this before in other situations. Something is missing and I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

From the examples given on the [NestedAttributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) api page, I would think your `subscription_attributes` update should look more like this

```
"subscription_attributes" => [ {"id" => "11", "workhours"=>"20"}, {"id" => "12", "workhours"=>"303"}, {"id" => "9", "workhours"=>"120"}, {"id" => "10", "workhours"=>"10"} ]
```

So you might need to change up your form to pass the ids for the update.